# Access NSTableView Datasource from Table Subclass

Tags: nstableview, appkit, nsmenu

*Swift 5, Xcode 11 beta*

I am setting up a contextual menu on an `NSTableView` subclass so that when a user control-clicks a bunch of rows in the table, I'll be able to take action on them (like archive them).

I can get the menu to work, but I don't understand how to access the datasource which is defined in the `NSTableView`'s parent view controller.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
class ListTable: NSTableView{
  override func validateProposedFirstResponder(_ responder: NSResponder, for event: NSEvent?) -> Bool {
    return true
  }

  override func menu(for event: NSEvent) -> NSMenu? {
    let menu = NSMenu()
    menu.addItem(withTitle: "Archive", action: #selector(archiveTheseEntries), keyEquivalent: "")
    return menu
  }

  @objc func archiveTheseEntries(){
    print(self.selectedRowIndexes) <-- This works

    for row in self.selectedRowIndexes{
      //How do I get access to my datasource? This doesn't seem to work...
      //let entry = self.dataSource?.tableView?(self, objectValueFor: self.tableColumns[0], row: row)
    }

  }
}
```

I know I can set up the `NSMenu` in a storyboard and use an `IBAction` to connect the `Archive` action, but I was hoping to get this method to work.

Comment: How do you set the data source of the table view?

Comment: The `tableView` is in a view controller where the datasource gets set, and then I extend that view controller like this: `extension ListVC: NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource{ ... }`

Comment: `self.dataSource` should work. Did you check the value?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. If I reference `self.dataSource.self` then I discovered that it points to the view controller where my datasource is defined.

```
@objc func archiveTheseEntries(){

  guard let entryVC = self.dataSource as? EntryVC else{ return }

  var entries = [Entry]()
  for row in self.selectedRowIndexes{
    entries.append(entryVC.entries[row]) <-- entryVC.entries contains my table data
  }
  //...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure. I was surprised by that myself. But it works. :)

Comment: Hmm... it **does** work without `.self`. I thought it wasn't working before without it. Answer updated. Thanks!